# smach_viewer problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

smach_viewer is reporting an error when I'm trying to visualize my state machine. It's displaying the state machine correctly and I can see the states changing, but when it gives me the following error message: http://pastebin.com/rfp7N914.

state_machines_library is not my package, it's just a subdirectory in my package src directory where I put some state machines.

Cheers,

Ugo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10118/smach_viewer-problem/) by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1620 on 2011-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-05-31**:
I'm using diamondback.  The executive_smach version is 1.0.1

**Comment by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on 2011-05-31**:
Which ros distribution are you using? What is the version of the executive_smach stack (see the CMakeList.txt file in the executive_smach root folder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Below is the relevant part of the smach code that is failing. It does not look very robust to changes in the exception. I created a ticket [here](http://https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4982). Could you post details about the ros/smach/python version you were using?

try:
self._local_data._data = pickle.loads(msg.local_data)
break
except ImportError as ie:
# This will only happen once for each package
modulename = ie.args[0][16:]
packagename = modulename[0:modulename.find('.')]
roslib.load_manifest(packagename)

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-05-31**:
Ok, I added the info to the ticket.